# Having trouble getting coordinates from Google Maps API Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps api and the directions service to retrieve information about two cities. My request retrieves json and I am using some of the response for other things, but I am not able to figure out how to get the coordinates from it.

As you can see they are listed as "a" and "b" under "Closure" and "[[Scopes]]" 
[from the json response in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxzne.png), but I am not able to access them by calling something like

```
json.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat["[[Scopes]]"][0].b
```

I get an error of "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

I think it has an something to do with it being inside [[Scopes]] but I can't figure out what to do

EDIT: to be clear my code looks something like this:

```
    var map;
    function initMap() {

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: {lat: 43.16, lng: -77.61}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
            directionsService.route({
                origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
                destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            }, function(response, status) {

                if (status === 'OK') {
                    getDirections(response);
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                } else {
                    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                }
            });

        };
        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', onChangeHandler);

    }

function getDirections(json) {
    var time = json.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
    time = time/3600;
    startCityLat = json.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat["[[Scopes]]"][];
    startCityLon = json.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat["[[Scopes]]"][0].b;
    endCityLat = json.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lat;
    endCityLon = json.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lng;
}

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Where in the getDirections function the time variable is retrieved fine, but start and end lat and lon are not

Comment: Can you post a short example code of how you got that JSON? What requests are you making?

Comment: @chrki I'm just using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXX&callback=initMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`start_location` is a [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object.  So you can use that directly, or if you want you can call the `.lat()` and `.lng()` functions.  Ignore the various things you can see when you log that LatLng object to the console; you can just do

```
startCityLat = json.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat();
startCityLon = json.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng();
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense! Thank you